# Aharnov cashier effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

What is the relation between magnetic moment generated by current distribution.through .It is given in the aharnov cashier paper attached below.can somebody throw some light[image]
How come the del cross thing in the paper

Comment: Please format your equations using MathJax instead of posting images. Posting images of equations is frowned upon.

Comment: It follows directly from Maxwell's equations given the definition of $\mathbf M$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Auxiliary_fields,_polarization_and_magnetization and if that indeed was your question, I'll post an answer too in order to close the question